# C# - Check for null values in IEnumerable<T> of different types

Tags: c#, .net, collections

How can I check for null values on `IEnumerable<T>` where T can be either a reference type or `Nullable<T>` type?

I receive an `object` parameter in an method that can be `IEnumerable<string>` or `IEnumerable<bool?>` or `IEnumerable<int?>` or `IEnumerable<Guid?>` and so on (it can also be non collection types... hence the `object` type). And I need to check for nulls.

So I tried something like `value is IEnumerable<object> objValue && objValue.Contains(null)` but that only works for reference types. When it's a `Nullable<>` it doesn't work because the lack of covariance on value types.

Is there a way that I can solve this without resorting to tons of reflection?

Answer (score 0):

I would have your current method handle only non-collection types. Make a new method that accepts an IEnumerable to handle checking the collections.

As for checking for null values, why not just do x == null or Object.Equals(x, null) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have own overload method for every case you need.

```
public void DoSomethingWith(IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    var notNullValues = values.Where(value => value != null).ToArray();

    // Do something with not null values
}

public void DoSomethingWith(IEnumerable<Nullable<T>> values)
{
    var notEmptyValues = values.Where(value => value.HasValue).ToArray();

    // Do something with not null values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple way is to take advantage of the fact that the `IEnumerable<T>` interface inherits the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface:

```
value is IEnumerable enumerable && enumerable.Cast<object>().Contains(null)
```

This is however a rather inefficient implementation since all items in a collection of value types will be boxed even if they're not nullable, which may be a performance concern depending on the size of the collections and how often this code is executed.